# Comparing SQL Server tables and finding matching outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to compare two tables, `A` and `B`, to find instances where `A` exists but an identical record does not exist in `B`.

Table A:

```sql
|PROJECT|ID|USER|DATE|
+-------+--+----+----+
|   2   |1 |ASD |0624|
|   3   |2 |FGH |0624|
```

Table B:

```sql
|PROJECT|ID|USER|DATE|
+-------+--+----+----+
|   2   |1 |ASD |0624|
```

I'd like to see my output like this:

```sql
|PROJECT|ID|USER|DATE|MATCHING_ID|
+-------+--+----+----+-----------+
|   2   |1 |ASD |0624|     1     |
|   3   |2 |FGH |0624|    NONE   |
```

I've tried something like this but I just syntax or ambiguous column name errors. I'm not fully sure what I'm doing wrong. I've followed a few examples but ended up in the same situation.

```sql
SELECT [PROJECT], [ID],  [USER], [DATE]
FROM [TABLE_A] 
LEFT JOIN [TABLE_B] ON [ID] = [ID]
WHERE [DATE] >= DATEADD(mm, -2, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Since you have tables with common column names, these columns need to be qualified. I.e. `[TABLE_A].[ID]`.

Comment: By identical do you mean all the columns or just the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `JOIN` conditions and use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT A.*, COALESCE(B.ID, 'NONE') as MATCHING_ID
FROM [TABLE_A] A LEFT JOIN
     [TABLE_B] B
     ON A.[ID] = B.[ID] AND
        A.[DATE] = B.[DATE] AND
        A.PROJECT = B.PROJECT AND
        A.USER = B.USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement and EXISTS:

```
SELECT a.*,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [TABLE_B] b
  WHERE a.PROJECT = b.PROJECT AND a.ID = b.ID AND a.USER = b.USER AND a.DATE = b.DATE
) THEN a.ID ELSE 'NONE' END MATCHING_ID
FROM [TABLE_A] a
```